# What is the best inheritance hierarchy for this model in C++?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, derived-class, dynamic-binding

[image]
I have the above class model exported as DLL to users. Considering user convenience  they will only require to instantiate a Base pointer, and use setMode(Mode) to initialize the Tank or Truck object. As they only need one tank or truck at any time, they can also use setMode(Mode) to reuse the pointer and initialize a new tank or truck.

Tank can only have Canon, Truck can only have Gun.

setMode(Mode) will initialize the weapon in the vehicle class respectively. setMode(Mode) looks something like this(please ignore pointer memory problem for now):

```
void Vehicle::setMode(Mode mode){
    this->mode = mode;
    if(mode == Tank){
        weapon = new Canon("owner");
    }else{
        weapon = new Gun("owner");
    }
}
```

My intention is that for user simplicity, they will only need to know about both base class Vehicle and Weapon, so that they use a Base Vehicle class and call getWeapon(Weapon*) to get a Base Weapon class, load up the weapon and set it back to the vehicle. Something like this:

```
//In case of Tank
Vehicle *vehicle = new Vehicle;
vehicle->setMode(Mode::Tank);
Weapon *weapon = vehicle->getWeapon();
weapon->setColor("red"); //Canon only function
weapon->reload();
vehicle->setWeapon(weapon);
vehicle->fire();
```

However as you can see, because it is a base pointer, it cannot call the derived class's setColor(String) function, so I put all the Canon and Gun specific functions to the base class as empty virtual function.

```
class Weapon{
    public:
        /*others as usual*/

    virtual setColor(String){} //Canon
    virtual setBullets(int){}  //Gun
}
```

But this seems to be wrong, Canon cannot setBullets() and Gun cannot setColor(), however there is no preventing users from getting a Canon object in a Weapon pointer and call the setBullets() function.

What would be a safer and more proper class model?

Comment: I am really wondering about your Vehicle derived classes also, since you set mode on the base class why do they even need to exist? What do they add?

Comment: I draw the graph wrong there, they are more like a private pointer insider the Vehicle class, to perform different fire() execution

Comment: TBH, you shouldn't abstract this so much. If `Tank` knows it should always own an object of type `Canon`, make it so. Same with `Truck` and `Gun`. No need for `Vehicle` to keep an instance of `Weapon`. This way you can also simply create another class `TurboTank` which has 3 cannons and 10 guns or `CarryTruck`, which has no weapons.

Comment: Totally agreeing with @Yksisarvinen – in addition, you should drop the `Mode` enum. `Vehicle::getWeapon()` would rather be pure virtual.

Comment: I see, so it is more a PIMPL approach with a private pointer. Inheritance is definitely a bit strange here, as you noticed with the `Weapon` and the derived classes methods. I think it may be that you are trying to be too dynamic at the wrong layer, I don't have a magic one size fits all answer to this. I would approach it from the perspective of your users and see what feels natural there.

Comment: Sidenote: As is (as mentioned, recommend to drop the mode entirely), your setMode has a memory leak: every but first call leaks the currently assigned weapon...

Comment: What is the C++ standard you have to support?

Comment: Your design is somewhat strange. Actual inheritance would make sense. setMode allows to convert a Tank to a Truck, which makes no sense. If I were you, I'd give Vehicle a factory instead. I'd also consider making Vehicle a pure abstract class.

Comment: Nitpicking OT: I think it's spelled "Cannon".

Comment: yes I agree that Vehicle side with setMode() is very odd and I will reimplement it as pure virtual base. However I think I still need this inheritance and abstraction for both vehicle and weapon since I have many other vehicles(boat, motorbike) and weapons(rocketlauncher, flamethrower,etc). That would be a lot of header files for the users, it seems not convenience.

Comment: However, because of that many derived weapons I had, I now have tons of virtual function obtained from the derived classes in the virtual base weapon class